# Elementor - [Responsiveness Issue] Columns width do not change on tablet and mobile

Tags: responsive-design, responsive, elementor, responsiveness

I am setting up 2 columns in elementor (ver. 3.7.8).
SECTION's content width is set to "BOXED".

**DESKTOP SETTINGS**
Left column's width is 30% AND Right column's width is 70%

**TABLET + MOBILE SETTINGS**
Left column's width is 100% AND Right column's width is 100%

This should make both columns take full width on tablets and mobiles.
But for some strange reason, both columns keep their desktop setting on tablet & mobile.
Even if I change the SECTION's content width to "FULL WIDTH", still the column percentages don't work properly.

Can someone guide if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue - manually forcing the regeneration of the css files solved my problem.

In the backend go to Elementor > Tools > General > Regenerate CSS & Data - force the regeneration of the CSS files.